# multiprocess read one file in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have a very very big txt.file(about 20G), can I use multi-process to read the whole file instead of read it from the first line to last?

For instance, I have 4 processes, and then I count the lines of the file first (suppose it have 2000 lines). Process 1 reads line 1~500, and process 2 reads 501~1000, I want to know is it possible(If one process is reading, can another process read at the same time?). Maybe this question is about how the split the txt file.

If it is ok. How to do it?
The code for one process the file is like this:

```
file = open(file_path,"r",encoding = 'utf-8')
alllines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for line in alllines:
    to do...
```

I have no idea how the change the alllines to become the numbers.Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of "maybe" in your question. What *is* your question? What do you want to do with the content of the file?

Comment: Why do you want the multiprocess do? The effience?

Comment: It's possible to do this, but disk I/O is a serial operation; you can't have multiple threads/processes reading from different parts of the disk in parallel - the disk reads will end up jumping back and forth between different parts of the file depending on which thread is active, which will usually make performance worse than if you just did it in a single thread.

Comment: First of all: if you don't have SSD or RAID then you won't gain any speed boost because HDD will serialize parallel reads anyway. Secondly you can't really do what you want, since you don't know where (in the file) line 501 is without reading all previous lines. So yeah, processing 20GB line-by-line will take time.

Comment: Do you need the whole file in memory at one time? You can say `for line in file:` and read in one line at a time.

Comment: If the processing of each line is compute intensive then multiprocessing maybe a good solution but a multiprocessing read isn't going to help for the reasons mentioned. Given compute intensive handling then you can have one thread read the file into a Queue and have worker threads read off the Queue to handle each line

Comment: @Tichodroma I just want to search how many times that a term occur in this file. Using multi-processes will speed up this program I think. If process 1 can search 1 to 500 lines. And another process can search the next 500 lines. The search will be much more quickly than using only one process.

Comment: @BlackMamba Yeah, I just want my program to be quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You could try memory mapping the file. See mmap: [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/mmap.html)

You can then read the file via the multiprocessing tasks, accessing the mapped file rather than the HDD.